# Pseudocode find biggest number in list

Tags: javascript, html, pseudocode, minimax

I have come across a question i am trying to answer but cant seems to figure it out, if someone can help me, please.

The intended functionality of the program below is to take a list of more than 1000 numbers (not in sequence) and determine the biggest number in the list. Identify any error(s) within this pseudocode solution and provide an explanation on why you identified this as a potential problem.

```
Let maxNumber represent the biggest number, set it to zero to start
While there are still numbers left in the list
    Look at the next number in the list
    Compare it to the maxNumber
        If next number is smaller than maxNumber
            Set maxNumber to that number
Report maxNumber as the biggest in the list
```

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried till now and where exactly you're stuck? Looks like a homework problem to me!

Answer (score 1):

What if they are all negative numbers. You code will return `0` which is not even in the list. You should set `maxNumber` to the first number in the list before looping.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the biggest number, setting maxNumber to the larger numbers is a procedure.

(Still, the question seems too basic.)

```
Let maxNumber represent the biggest number, set it to zero to start
While there are still numbers left in the list
    Look at the next number in the list
    Compare it to the maxNumber
        If next number is **bigger** than maxNumber
            Set maxNumber to that number
Report maxNumber as the biggest in the list
```

Else, set maxNumber to the first element in the list for a more precise and valid output.

```
Let maxNumber represent the first number in the list
While there are still numbers left in the list
    Look at the next number in the list
    Compare it to the maxNumber
        If next number is **bigger** than maxNumber
            Set maxNumber to that number
Report maxNumber as the biggest in the list
```